# Remove <strong> elements from links only using jQuery

Tags: jquery

I am trying to remove `<strong>` element from links only from a `div`. The following removes all the `<strong>` tags where I just want to remove `<strong>` from only links not other `<strong>` tags in the same div.

```js
jQuery("#left-area").find("strong").contents().unwrap();
```

*For example:*

I want to keep this **bold phrase** with `<strong>` tags but do not want `<strong>` in all **[links]**[1](https://stackoverflow.com/) in the div.

Comment: don't include strong tag in your html, and keep bol *a* tag by css

Comment: why adding the strong tag directly to your html?
 you can easily style it from css Like: `div{ font-weight: 600}; or 700` in most cases

Comment: Can you provide an *html* example?  ie is your code `<strong><a>..</a></strong>` or `<a>..<strong>..</strong>..</a>`?  In which case it would be: `jQuery("#left-area").find("a").find("strong").contents().unwrap()`

Comment: @Girish Thanks for your comment. Yes, I know. But my blog is a multi author blog where authors posts articles. But even though making any links bold is disallowed still they use bold tags from the editor. Hence, I want to remove them grammatically

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could select the anchor tags with `strong a` and then the parent `strong` tag again. If you have the `strong` tags inside the anchor tags you simply need to select `a strong`.

**Working example:**

```js
$("#left-area").find("strong a").parents('strong').contents().unwrap();
$("#left-area").find("a strong").contents().unwrap();
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="left-area">

  <strong>
    <p>bold phrase</p>
  </strong>
  
  <strong>
    <a href="#">link</a>
  </strong>
  
  <a href="#"><strong>link</strong></a>
  
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks. It did work. But how to make it work in such cases? <a href="#"><strong>Anchor Text</strong></a>

Comment: Thank you very much biberman. Both of them worked now. Thanks once again.